# Create a single config file for Toolbar or TextEditor in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have the following config for the PrimeNG TextEditor used in multiple components in an Angular project. I want to define this config in a file and retrieve it from all of the necessary components instead of defining multiple times on the components. What is the best way to perform this? Creating a new component? I know it is possible by creating a components but I am not sure if it is best practices. Any help please?

```
toolbarOptions: any = [
    [{ 'header': [3, false] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
    [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'align': [] }],
    ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
];
```

Comment: You can use a service that return your options.

Comment: But having a service for the sole purpose of just returning an array is a little overkill

Comment: Overkill for what? :D I use this technique for a side-bar to dynamically load the side-bar items.

Comment: Another idea would be to have a generic component which receive as input a config object. You can define your object in a separated while, where you keep constants for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an abstract class in a file with your toolbar config info like:

```
export abstract class ToolbarConfig {
    static toolbarOptions: any = [
        [{ 'header': [3, false] }],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
        ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
        [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
        [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],
        [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
        [{ 'align': [] }],
        ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
    ];
};
```

Making sure to make `toolbarOptions` `static`.

Then import your config into any file like:

```
import { ToolbarConfig } from '../configs/app.config';
```

And use the `toolbarOptions` anywhere you want like so:

```
ToolbarConfig.toolbarOptions
```

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to wrap the textEditor in a new component and define your toolbarOptions in there.

If you ever need to use your new component, but include or exclude some features from the editor, you could make your new component take an `@Input() toolbarOptions` that overrides the default config for specific use-cases.

Remember that if your component is to be used in reactive forms it must implement the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface.

The options itself could be defined in a service (in general components should be as small as possible). You could even make a function that takes an enum that defines which configuration you need (if you ever need more than one).

But having a service for the sole purpose of just returning an array is a little overkill.

Another option is simply just exporting the const in a seperate file like `export const toolbarOptions = ....` and then you can import it in the components where you need it. You could also create a class with a static function to return the option.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I agree with you but there are some of the extra controller and I just need to define this config and get from multiple components. Any idea regarding to this? Shall I create a component and type this config in it?

Comment: Thanks. I exported the const in a seperate file, but also keeping mind that there will be another config I need in this file. I tried to create class and remove export from the const, but not working. Any idea how to manage this? Could you post example code pls that enable us to use multiple config as const?